# HttpClient Post request with Bearer token

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Возникли сложности при взаимодействии с [API](https://sendpulse.com/ru/integrations/api#send-email-smtp). Ни как не могу произвести `POST` запрос для осуществления отправки письма, в ответ получаю `400 ошибку`. Беда заключается в том, что не могу понять в чем проблема, помогите разобраться.

Для отправки письма использую следующий код:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
     new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var url = "https://api.sendpulse.com/smtp/emails/";
var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result; // 400 Ошибка
```

`Json` данные:

```
{
   "text" : "Мой текст",
   "subject" : "Моя тема",
   "from" : {
        "name" : "Admin",
        "email" : "myEmail@yandex.ru"
 },
 "to" : [
       {
     "name" : "Client",
     "email" : "client1@yandex.ru"
       }
    ]
 }
```

P.S.

1) Авторизационный токен получен корректно, для проверки отправлял с данным токеном `Get` запросы все ОК.

2) `Json` данные валидны, проверял их на корректность сериализатором  [JsonSerializer](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm).

Comment: Json данные тоже покажите. Только адреса электронной почты замаскируйте звёздочками. Потому что на сторонний взгляд ошибок в коде нет. Разве что в документации указан адрес `https://api.sendpulse.com/smtp/emails`, а у вас к нему добавлен завершающий символ косой черты — `https://api.sendpulse.com/smtp/emails/`. Может быть, у данного сервиса это имеет значение.

Comment: Обновил. Добавил `Json` данные. На самом деле,  я пробовал у адреса https://api.sendpulse.com/smtp/emails обратный слеш и убирать и оставлять, но толку не было. В общем по-всякому уже изгалялся ))

Comment: Из того, что ещё видно: не все поля из примера API присутствуют у вас. Возможно, `html` обязательное поле. Возможно также `bcc` обязательное поле и должно быть пустым массивом. В целом же, конечно, правильнее обратиться в саппорт сервиса, прислав им свой JSON.

Comment: Я с сапортом общался, максимум чем помогли, так это сказали что ошибка на вашей (т.е. моей) стороне, ищите. На счет `html` и прочих атрибутов, я узнавал, они не являются все обязательными, а используются при необходимости. Мол если отправляется `html` версия письма, то `html` используется, иначе достаточно просто `text`. Хотя я в ходе своих экспериментов, пробовал оставлять все атрибуты из приведенного в документации массива, за исключением `html` и `attachments`, но результат все тот же.

Comment: В нашем проекте вызов делается через `ObjectContent`: `var content = new ObjectContent(typeof(SendParamters), sendParamters, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()); var result = client.PostAsync(uri, content);` Здесь `SendParameters` это C#-класс в котором описаны JSON-атрибуты. Типа `public class User { public string name { get; set; } public string email { get; set; } } public class SendParameters { public string text { get; set; } public string html { get; set; } public string subject { get; set; } public User from { get; set; } public IEnumerable<User> to { get; set; } ...}`. Попробуйте.

Comment: Не помогло. В общем подоставал я их техподдержку, обещали что-то со своей стороны  проверить и сообщить по  результату.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачайте пример реализации REST API для C# по ссылке https://github.com/sendpulse/sendpulse-rest-api-csharp

Затем используйте этот пример кода для отправки письма:

```
    // https://login.sendpulse.com/settings/#api
    private static string userId = "_ВАШ_userId_";
    private static string secret = "_ВАШ_secret_";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sendpulse sp = new Sendpulse(userId, secret);

        Dictionary<string, object> from = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        from.Add("name", "SENDER_NAME");
        from.Add("email", "SENDER_EMAIL@domain.com");
        ArrayList to = new ArrayList();
        Dictionary<string, object> elementto = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        elementto.Add("name", "Test email");
        elementto.Add("email", "test@test.com");
        to.Add(elementto);
        Dictionary<string, object> emaildata = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        emaildata.Add("html", "<b>Hello</b>");
        emaildata.Add("text", "Hello!");
        emaildata.Add("subject", "Send SMTP email");
        emaildata.Add("from", from);
        emaildata.Add("to", to);
        Dictionary<string, object> result = sp.smtpSendMail(emaildata);
        Console.WriteLine("Response Status {0}", result["http_code"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Result {0}", result["data"]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Либо же подключите в ваш проект классы по работе с SendPulse REST API, скачав их по ссылке [SendPulse.restapi](https://github.com/sendpulse/sendpulse-rest-api-csharp/tree/master/Sendpulse-rest-api/SendPulse.restapi)
Для подключения используйте:

```
using Sendpulse_rest_api.restapi;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас простое текстовое письмо, то можно подставить для поля "html" пустую строку. Это все-таки обязательный параметр.